# How to remove Map from list in Dart | Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have a json list. from this i want to delete a particular item. Below is my code.

```
final List _vehicleList = [
    {
      'vehicleNumber': 'KL-14-V-5208',
      'vehicleType': 'Two Wheeler',
    },
    {
      'vehicleNumber': 'KL-13-H-8880',
      'vehicleType': 'Four Wheeler',
    },
    {
      'vehicleNumber': 'KL-14-M-6889',
      'vehicleType': 'Three Wheeler',
    },
  ];
```

This is my list. Here from this i want to delete the item based on vehicleNumber when i press a delete button. I'am using listview builder. When i print the list after the button press nothing happens
This is my UI Code.

```
                       return Column(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  _vehicleList[index]['vehicleNumber'],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  _vehicleList[index]['vehicleType'],
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('Deleted');
                                  _vehicleList.removeAt(_vehicleList[index]);
                                  print(_vehicleList);
                                },
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.timesCircle,
                                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
```

Comment: If it is a `StatefulWidget`, you need to call `setState()` for the state change to reflect in the UI.

Comment: That i already done. The problem is when i print the list after delete, the item is not deleted. it is still in list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you. just pass your index

```
_vehicleList.removeWhere((element) => element["vehicleNumber"] == 'KL-14-V-5208');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change like this;

Before;

```dart
_vehicleList.removeAt(_vehicleList[index]);
```

after

```dart
_vehicleList.removeAt(index);
```

Documentation of how to use the "removeAt" method. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeAt.html

Comment: Cool. It Works :)